# Error - Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I want to connect my java program to connect with database and retrieve the data.
its compile perfectly but runtime
im getting this `Error : Could not find or load main class`

i have installed the Java SQL driver and added the jar path to the Environmental variable as CLASSPATH

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Java2Sql{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:80/";
        String dbName = "test";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "root";

        try{
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String strsql = "SELECT * FROM student";

            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(strsql);

            while(res.next()){
                System.out.println("ID :"+res.getString(1));
                System.out.println("Name :"+res.getString(2));
                System.out.println("Tel :"+res.getString(3));
                System.out.println("City :"+res.getString(4));
            }
            res.close();
            conn.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you running the jar?

Comment: Downloaded the jar file and and gave the jar file path to the Environment variable as CLASSPATH

Comment: Yes, but you have to call a main class from somewhere, right?

Comment: Could you provide the exception stacktrace?

Comment: @luanjot you mean same folder that jar file in? then im getting Exception java.lang.classnotfoundexception : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: It means you don't have driver for mysql. Download and add driver jar file into library.

Comment: Mind Peace : what does that mean?

Comment: When you do Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); it calls driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. As you don't have that into classpath it fails

Comment: @MindPeace Hi I added to the Libaray. now after running im not getting anything. No error message or Output :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with JDBC whatsoever. It's just a manifest problem in the JAR file.

Comment: hi I am facing the same issue can you please tell me if you have found any solution to the run the application through terminal. if its of any use i am using Linux mint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should download Driver from [HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html)

and JAR file need to add to project class path.

First Right click on you Eclipse Project,  Project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path. Under Libraries tab, click Add Jars or "Add External JARs" and add downloaded jar

Not 100% sure but looks like you are using wrong port number 80. Make sure your MySQL port number is current by below statement

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';
```

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with JDBC, the driver, the port, etc.

Comment: @EJB then can you tell me the problem?

Comment: If you read all comment carefully you will see below comment from original creator - then im getting Exception java.lang.classnotfoundexception : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: @MindPeace Thank god finally its worked. i think its better to use eclipse without using command prompt.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say your `Java2Sql` is inside `test` package.

### Folder Structure:

[image]

And the code you are trying to run is as below.

### Code:

```
package test;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Java2Sql {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "username", "pwd"); // Test DB
            System.out.println("Connected.");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Commands you need to compile and run would be:

```
javac Java2Sql.java
java -classpath .;test/mysql-connector-java-5.0.4-bin.jar test.Java2Sql
```

### Compilation and Execution:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. need to try with CMD again

Answer (score 1):

The class named in the manifest Main-class entry doesn't exist in your JAR file, or possibly there is no Main-class: entry in the manifest.

You haven't needed to call Class.forName() for about seven years, and you needs rendered to call newInstance() after that.

Answer (score 0):

Default port for mysql connections is 3306. So change this line

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:80/";
```

to this:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
```

Comment: This is indeed a problem in the code but it doesn't account for the error the OP is getting.