# ClassNotFoundException java

Tags: java, mysql, classnotfoundexception

I have a doubt about Class Not Found Exception. I've added all the jars in my file but I cant seem to make it work. I've added the mysql-connector.jar in my project. DOes anyone know how to make it right?

```
try {
    String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    Class.forName(driverName);

    String serverName = "localhost";
    String mydatabase = "UFRJSocial";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + mydatabase;
    String username = "root";
    String password = "";

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

    if (connection != null) {
        status = ("STATUS--->Connected!");
    } else {
        status = ("STATUS--->The connection failed");
    }

    return connection;

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("The specified driver was nor found");
    //THIS IS THE LINE THAT MY CONSOLE IS SHOWING
    return null;
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("it was not possible to connect to the database.");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: How are you running your program? What is your classpath set to?

Comment: You may want to check this [piece of code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453794/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class/25454247#25454247) on how to connect to your MySQL database using Java.

Comment: I'm running it at Eclipse jee with Tomcat7 . This code is not mine, so i actually cannot find yet what my classpath is set to. I'm gonna search here

Comment: Wrong classpath, thats all I can say

Comment: and how can i make it right?

Comment: In the stack trace - which class does it say is missing?

Comment: only two classes i can think of that might cause error from that code is Driver or DriverManager. mysql-connector as Driver. Maybe you are missing the jdbc jar for java.sql.DriverManager? You should run line by line in debug mode to see what line is throwing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make it work. It was missing the mysql.jar file in the Web-INF folder.

Comment: So you can mark it answered then, yes? You can add an answer yourself and check that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code please:

```
enter code
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import app.dao.connector.DatabaseManager;

public class MySQLDatabaseManager implements DatabaseManager{
@Override
public Connection getConnection() {
    final String USER_NAME  ="root";
    final String PASSWORD = "1234";
    final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory system";

    Connection conn = null;

    try{
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
    }
```

As You can see, I tried to declare all my variables outside the try and catch block. In declaring the **JDBC_URL** specify your database.