# Connecting to MySQL database using Java in command prompt

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Since I don't have netbeans right now, I am trying to connect to MySQL database from my Java code through command prompt. But it it is not taking the mysql-coonectivity.jar file.

Does anyone know any way to run my program??? Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by `it is not taking`? Also, please consider adding the code you are trying to run. You may also want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453794/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class/25454247#25454247).

Comment: Please help us help you. What program? Does it work in netbeabs? How is it *not taking the file*? Have you checked the spelling?

Comment: As you are new user here, let me tell you, if you find the solution of your problem here in the answers, then you should accept the answer, to let others know what worked for you. To do so, you should click on the right sign tick on the left side of answer below the up down arrows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try executing the program as it is windows OS

```
java -cp .;path\of\your\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar className
```

In case you don't have the mysql-connector-java-[version].jar  get it from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add your MySQL connector jar file while compiling and running your program, you can do it the following way,

To compile :

`javac -g -cp mysql-coonectivity.jar; YourFileName.java`

To Run

`java -cp mysql-coonectivity.jar; YourMainClass`

NOTE: The above written syntax assumes that your jar file is present at same location as of your program.

Comment: my program has compiled successfully but when i try to execute it, i get an error when i try to run, i get an exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. Please help.

Comment: @user3359330  NoClassDefFoundError for which class?

Answer (score 0):

To execute program in Linux (Ubuntu) OS follow the below command format:

```
java -cp .:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar MainProgram
```

***Note:***

> 1. Assuming you are in the directory where MainProgram.class is exist
> 2. After .(dot -- this is for current directory) there is :(colon) as a separator in Linux